# Getting "database is locked" error when trying to write to a GeoPackage database

Tags: c#, gdal, geopackage

I'm using the OGR/GDAL C# managaged API to write to a GeoPackage database and I keep running into a "database is locked" error when I try to sync the database to disk.  After much experimentation, this appears to only happen if I first open the GeoPackage to do a read, close the db (Dispose the DataSource), reopen db and attempt to write.  Web searches indicate that this error occurs if the GDAL and SQLite objects from the read are not disposed before attempting the write.  However, I think I'm disposing all the managed objects properly so I'm wondering if there is a call that I'm missing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've included a sample Console app that shows the error I'm getting. It creates a new layer but I get same error if I try updating an existing layer.  I'm using GeoPackage v1.2, GDAL v2.3, and SQLite v3.21.0 on Windows.

Example Console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OSGeo.OGR;
namespace GeoPackageWriteTest
{
  class GeoPackageTest
  {
    public static void usage()
    {
      Console.WriteLine( "usage (to create a new layer):" );
      Console.WriteLine( "gpkgWriteTest {gpkg filename} {layername}" );
      System.Environment.Exit( 0 );
    }
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
      if ( args.Length < 2 )
        usage();

      Ogr.RegisterAll();

      // simulate an object opening a geopackage db to do a simple read
      Console.WriteLine( "Opening database readonly: " + args[0] );
      DataSource dataSource1 = Ogr.OpenShared( args[0], 0 ); // open readonly
      if ( dataSource1 == null )
        throw new ArgumentException( string.Format( "Error opening GeoPackage database: {0}", args[0] ) );
      using ( dataSource1 )
      {
        Driver driver = dataSource1.GetDriver();
        if ( driver == null )
          throw new ArgumentException( "Error getting GDAL driver!" );
        Console.WriteLine( "Using driver: " + driver.name );

        string pfile = GetParameterTableName( dataSource1 );
        Console.WriteLine( "Parameter table: " + pfile );
      } // DataSource gets disposed and geopackage is closed
      dataSource1 = null;

      // make sure all Disposed objects are garbage collected
      // (just trying to see if it makes a difference, it doesn't)
      GC.Collect( GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true );
      GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

      // simulate another object reopening a geopackage db to do a simple write
      Console.WriteLine( "Opening database readwrite: " + args[0] );
      DataSource dataSource2 = Ogr.OpenShared( args[0], 1 );  // reopen readwrite
      if ( dataSource2 == null )
        throw new ArgumentException( string.Format( "Error opening GeoPackage database: {0}", args[0] ) );
      using ( dataSource2 )
      {
        List<string> options = new List<string>();
        options.Add( "SPATIAL_INDEX=YES" );

        Console.WriteLine( "Creating layer: " + args[1] );
        Layer tableLayer = dataSource2.CreateLayer( args[1], null, wkbGeometryType.wkbNone, options.ToArray() );
        if ( tableLayer == null )
          throw new ArgumentException( string.Format( "Error creating layer: {0}", args[2] ) );

        int rc = Ogr.OGRERR_NONE;
        int approx_ok = 1;
        int fieldCount = 3;
        for ( int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++ )
        {
          //FieldDefn fieldDefn = GetFieldDefn( args[n], args[n + 1] );
          string fname = string.Format( "TestField{0}", i );
          FieldDefn fieldDefn = GetFieldDefn( fname, "int32" );
          rc = tableLayer.CreateField( fieldDefn, approx_ok );
          if ( rc != Ogr.OGRERR_NONE )
            throw new ArgumentException( string.Format( "Error creating field: {0}", fname ) );
        }
        // write changes to disk
        Console.WriteLine( "Writing changes to disk..." );
        dataSource2.FlushCache(); // this throws database locked error
      }
    }
    static string GetParameterTableName( DataSource ogrDataSource )
    {
      try
      {
        string s = string.Empty;
        string sql = "select * from sqlite_master where type='table' and name like '%Parameter%'";
        OSGeo.OGR.Layer layer = ogrDataSource.ExecuteSQL( sql, null, "SQLITE" );
        using ( layer )
        {
          layer.ResetReading();
          OSGeo.OGR.Feature fea = layer.GetNextFeature();
          if ( fea != null )
          {
            s = fea.GetFieldAsString( "name" );
          }
        }
        return s;
      }
      catch ( Exception )
      {
        return string.Empty;
      }
    }
    private static FieldDefn GetFieldDefn( string fldName, string fldType )
    {
      //OSGeo.OGR.FieldType fieldType = GetOGRFieldType( fldType );
      OSGeo.OGR.FieldType fieldType = FieldType.OFTInteger;
      OSGeo.OGR.FieldSubType subType = FieldSubType.OFSTNone;

      FieldDefn fieldDefn = new FieldDefn( fldName, fieldType );
      fieldDefn.SetSubType( subType );
      return fieldDefn;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are setting `dataSource1` to `null`. Try `FlushCache()` instead.

Comment: I'm calling FlushCache() in the block that is attempting the write (which is throwing the database locked error).  Also calling FlushCache() in the block doing the read operation doesn't change the behavior (I just tried to make sure).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone was curious.  The issue here was in the way I was reading the result set layer the first time.  I only read 1 feature (as that was all I was interested in).  Evidently that leaves the result set in a busy state.  I needed to either read the entire layer, i.e.

```
      OSGeo.OGR.Feature fea = layer.GetNextFeature();
      while ( fea != null )
      {
        s = fea.GetFieldAsString( "name" );
        layer.GetNextFeature();
      }
```

Or I needed to reset the layer after reading, i.e.

```
      OSGeo.OGR.Feature fea = layer.GetNextFeature();
      if ( fea != null )
      {
        s = fea.GetFieldAsString( "name" );
      }
      layer.ResetReading();
```